# ORMLite loading parent table without foreign Objects

Tags: ormlite

Example:
I've got payments and every payment has n article in a foreign table.
So now just want to query all the payment data without its article information.

Did i have specify all columns which are needed for a payment or is there a keyword or another mechanism in ormlite to do something like that.

Answer (score 0):

> So now just want to query all the payment data without its article information.

So if every payment has articles in a foreign table then you are talking about a `ForeignCollection`.  You can make this collection be lazy loaded (i.e. `eager = false`) so it will not be queried on at all.

If you are talking about a single foreign object then it will create the object but the object will only have the id field set unless you use `foreignAutoRefresh = true`.  It is false by default.

> Did i have specify all columns which are needed for a payment or is there a keyword or another mechanism in ormlite to do something like that.

You certainly can limit your columns in the `Payment` query but you shouldn't have to.